# How can I insert a row containing both a default value and a constructed object?

Tags: database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Impossible Snowflake insert: VALUES + OBJECT_CONSTRUCT or SELECT + DEFAULT

I have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE scenarios
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    information OBJECT NOT NULL
);
```

I believe there is no way to properly add a record:

```
INSERT INTO scenarios (id, information)
VALUES (default, object_construct('type','new','size','medium'));
```

throws error on OBJECT_CONSTRUCT being inside of VALUES; on the other hand

```
INSERT INTO scenarios (id, information)
SELECT default, object_construct('type','new','size','medium');
```

throws error on DEFAULT being inside of SELECT.

How should I insert an object and a default value simultaneously?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-semistructured#example-of-inserting-an-object) :

> To insert `OBJECT` data directly, use IIS (`INSERT INTO ... SELECT`).
>
> ```
> The following code uses the `OBJECT_CONSTRUCT` function to construct the `OBJECT` that it inserts.
>
> INSERT INTO object_example (object_column)
> SELECT OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('thirteen', 13::VARIANT, 'zero', 0::VARIANT);
> ```

Your second query is nearly correct, rather than using the invalid *DEFAULT*, use `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` instead :

```
INSERT INTO scenarios (create_time, information)
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, object_construct('type','new','size','medium');
```

Comment: I mistyped the question original; the first column is an id field: IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE. Hence it needs to be populated with DEFAULT.

Answer (score 0):

firstly, removing the object question and just looking at the identity column, the id just should not be mentioned in the insert:

```
CREATE or replace TABLE scenarios
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    ,abc int not null
    --,information OBJECT NOT NULL
);
```

```
insert into scenarios(abc) values 
    (1),(10),(100);
```

and now check

```
select * from scenarios ;
```

| ID | ABC |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 100 |

and you are then you observation is correct that VALUES section need to be all static known values (because it is a compile time step) verse SELECT which will actually run on a compute node, to evaluate, (albeit some SELECT options can be resolved in the compile stage).

Thus you OBEJCT creation has to be via a select:

```
CREATE or replace TABLE scenarios
(
    id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL UNIQUE
    ,abc int not null
    ,information OBJECT NOT NULL
);

insert into scenarios(abc, information) 
    select 123,
        object_construct('type','new','size','medium');
    
select * from scenarios ;
```

| ID | ABC | INFORMATION |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | { "size": "medium", "type": "new" } |